# How can I create a remote database for my heroku application

Tags: python, django, database, heroku

I have created a web app using django and I have deployed that app on web using heroku.. But the problem is that I don't have any remote database so whenever I make new users on my local branch and add some other features and then merge this branch with the master branch(which i have set up to deploy on heroku) the users that i added on my localhost get added to heroku deployed website..I know that databases can be stored on AWS but I don't have a credit card to login..Please tell me some other tool using which I can keep my local database and online database separate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku does offer a Postgres addon for free: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql.
They also provide documentation on how it works: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#provision-a-database

Django Girls has a great tutorial that explains how you can deploy a Django app to Heroku along with a Postgres database: https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/heroku/

To sum it up, you have to get the Heroku Postgress addon and then you will have to update your project's `settings.py` to use the Postgres database:

```
# Load operating system environment variables and then prepare to use them
env = environ.Env()

DATABASES = {
    # Raises ImproperlyConfigured exception if DATABASE_URL not in os.environ
    'default': env.db('DATABASE_URL'),
}
```

Having the database url that Heroku providers added as an environment variable: `DATABASE_URL`

I would recommend configuring your Django project to also use a local Postgres database while developing locally to avoid any surprises when deploying to production.